# Simple Rails Login System

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got a simple rails application where I have a model "users" where each row (user) has an id, a username and a password.

I have a view for a "login" page where I want the user to insert a username and a password, and I want these to be forwarded to a code which verifies if there are any matches in the database for such combination. If so, I would like for a session to be initialized for the user.

I would also like to be able to restrict access to certain pages depending on whether the session has been set. (Ie: The user has been logged in)

Now, what I would normally do as I am used to PHP would be to set the "action" of the form to some PHP page where I would make a request to the server for such values, and then inserting them in a query to the database. If the number of rows returned was greater than 0, the user would be authenticated.

Is there a similar as simple method in rails?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment yet, but I fully agree with Tetsu's answer.

To elaborate further, Devise is the best Ruby on Rails way to implement user authentication. You don't want to go about creating your own authentication and have to worry about encrypting passwords and whatnot. Trust me, it's a train wreck. Devise is updated constantly, providing the most secure solution Rails has to offer.

In your Gemfile: `gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.4'`

Watch this RailsCast on Devise: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

After you have that all set up, you can load a page conditionally based on whether or not the user is signed in (or redirect him or her). Here's an example:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the way of `PHP`, but IMHO simplest way to implement user authentication is to use gem, like `Devise`.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise